# How to use D3.format for dynamic values having different numbers?

Tags: d3.js

Does anyone know how to use D3.format for dynamic values having decimal nos(2 points after decimal) or a millionth number at a time?

I can write only : `yFormat={d => d3.format('s')(d)}`
or `yFormat={d => d3.format('.1f')(d)}`

Is there any way to write it together because my values are dynamic.Something like this :

```
yFormat={d => d3.format('.1f','s')(d)}
```

If I write like this it is taking only the first format and not the second.

Please check this link : http://koaning.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/html/d3format.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this to provide dynamic tick format:

```
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(0) + ",0)")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .call(d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(20)
    .tickFormat(function(d) {
      if (d < 1000) //checking a condition based on that do foarmat
        //provide a format
        return d3.format("s")(d);
      else {
       //provide some other format  
       return d; 
      }

    }));
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/7Odk0qyEeH7fY6RZe97u?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks a lot..Cyril..:)